# Local wordpress backup not working

Tags: php, lamp, wordpress, php7

I am trying to run a local copy of a live wordpress site (for example, as described [here](https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-local-copy-of-a-live-wordpress-site)).

LAMP / file permissions are working fine. However, wordpress gives me the following error message:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

I have `php5-mysql` installed (which seems to be the extension that wordpress is expecting to use). However, my LAMP server seems to be running PHP 7.0, the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` starting with

> PHP Version 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

I am guessing that the wordpress installation (version 3.4.2) is requiring a LAMP server with PHP 5 to be able to use the `php5-mysql` extension.

- Is is possible to downgrade LAMP to use php5, in order to get the local copy running? (Provided I have identified the problem correctly.)
- What other options do I have on my local machine?
- How do I best upgrade the live site?

Comment: There is a package `php-mysql`  which I believe is actually PHP 7.

Comment: @Jos Thank you for the comment. However,  Wordpress seems not to need that one... (the error message is still the same)

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with installing older or different versions of programs on your local Ubuntu environment.

[**Docker**](https://www.docker.com/) is the perfect tool for doing something like that.

There are a lot of ready-made [php5](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=1&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=php5&starCount=0) and/or [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=1&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=mysql&starCount=0) packages available.

You can start with a [apache+php5 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nimmis/apache-php5/) and install mysql into it by yourself or even better, use a separate [mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/).

---

[Installation](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/docker-installation-and-usage-on-ubuntu-16.04/):

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```